# Google Optimize reporting showing "no data collected" despite thousands of experiment impressions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-optimize

Google Optimize reporting shows thousands of experiment impressions, but claims no data was collected from Google Analytics ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryynk.png)).

Is this potentially related to the GA4 - Google Optimize outage on the 2nd? Anyone else having this issue?

I reviewed optimize settings and GA4 information. Have not set up custom dimensions within GA4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be the custom dimensions requirement in GA4, but something to look at would be do you have a situation where there is 0 traffic assigned to the control? I have experienced tests where I have two variants and a control and send 0 to the control, this results in some issues with GO data.